# C# Npgsql connection error: Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection doesn't implement interface System.Collections.IEnumerator

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, mono, npgsql

I refered npgsql.dll usign: -r:../../Bin/Npgsql.dll. 
The C# assembly does not give any errors.

When executing the following code:

```
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;database=myDatabase;uid=myName;password=myPassword;pooling=False;CommandTimeout=60;Timeout=60; Preload Reader = true;");
    conn.Open();
```

I get the following error:

```
    Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection doesn't implement interface System.Collections.IEnumerator

    Stacktrace:

      at Comparator.PairwiseAlignment.fetchData (BaseElements.Sample) <0x0011b>
      at Comparator.PairwiseAlignment.initiate (object) <0x00017>
      at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

    Native stacktrace:

        mono() [0x4983a9]
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf030) [0x7f12b9f22030]
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x7f12b9bba475]
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x180) [0x7f12b9bbd6f0]
        mono() [0x5cfcdf]
        mono() [0x5cfd62]
        mono() [0x49a06f]
        mono() [0x49a784]
        [0x4159cbba]

    Debug info from gdb:

    =================================================================
    Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
    a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
    used by your application.
    =================================================================
```

Remarkable is that the assembly done by the ASP.NET framework does not cause this error when attempting to connect to the database. But it does when I compile the program manualy via the command line. That makes me think the error is probably caused by some compatibility issue.

The ASP Web.config contains this line:

```
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

Therefor I compile via the command line with the "dmcs" module, which stands for version 4.

Comment: Please, give us the whole command you use to build the application manually.

Comment: `> dmcs -out:Comparator.exe *.cs base_elements/*.cs pipeline_elements/*.cs -r:../../Bin/Npgsql.dll -r:System.Configuration.dll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a .dll called "Mono.Security.dll".

Remarkable is that ASP.NET didn't include this file with the assembly neither. Still the system was able to function without it..